# Cant connect thermal printer to web host using php

Tags: php, thermal-printer

I am using a thermal printer to auto print a receipt using https://github.com/mike42/escpos-php library, it works fine on the localhost but when I try to use the printing function on the web host by Hostgator it gives me an error which says :

`Couldn't print to this printer: Failed to print. Command "smbclient '//gator4012.hostgator.com/POS-58C' -c 'print -' -N -m SMB2" failed with exit code 127: sh: smbclient: command not found`

here is my code

```
<?php 
 use Mike42\Escpos\PrintConnectors\FilePrintConnector;
 use Mike42\Escpos\PrintConnectors\WindowsPrintConnector;
 use Mike42\Escpos\Printer;
 use Mike42\Escpos\CapabilityProfile;

try {
// Enter the share name for your USB printer here5
$connector = new WindowsPrintConnector("POS-58C");
$printer= new Printer($connector);
/* Print a "Hello world" receipt" */

$printer -> text("Hello World!\n");
$printer -> cut();


$printer -> close();} catch(Exception $e) {
echo "Couldn't print to this printer: " . $e -> getMessage() . "\n"; }
```

I have tried to use network printing and it still doesn't work, I want to know what I have done wrong or if there is another method to print the receipt automatically without a print dialog box

Comment: Your web host and your printer live on two completely different networks. Unless your printer can access the outside world, or rather can BE accessed by the outside world, you're not going to be able to do it.

Comment: @aynber is it possible to use vpn to access the network?

Comment: Another problem, based on the error message details, could be that either smbclient isn't installed or isn't in the PATH for the webserver's user account.

Comment: `is it possible to use vpn to access the network`...we don't know anything about the network you're trying to connect to. So we can't answer that. Can you host the website on the same network as the printer?

Comment: @ADyson By same network you mean same hosting company that is in my country

Comment: I mean the same network where the printer is connected. I don't know where that is.

Comment: By network, that means same physical network. Think of it as houses. Your printer is in one house, it can talk to anyone in the same house even if it's in another room. HostGator is in another house, in another city, and needs special access to connect to the printer's house.

Comment: @ADyson the network that i am connected to is in OMAN the middle east as for Hostgator its in the US, what I am trying to do is host it online so I can assess it anywhere

Comment: @aynber ok now i understand that in order for the printer to work online it must have special access  to connect to the printer, so how can I do that

Comment: The geographical location is irrelevant. If they're not in the same LAN you can't make them talk to each other (at least not with some extra config and probably a big security risk). Simple. The two networks could be lying on the floor next to each other in the same room, but if there's a NAT router/firewall between them then the connection will fail.

Comment: If the printer is on a simple home network then you might be able to do it using port forwarding on the router, but it's a security risk. if it's a company network, they likely have a firewall and will likely not be comfortable allowing this traffic inbound, at least not without a ton of security and caveats.

Comment: `what I am trying to do is host it online so I can assess it anywhere`...but is that necessary, if you can't collect the receipt until you physically visit the printer? Or does someone else collect the printout?

Comment: @ADyson   I have created something like a kiosk system where when the user makes an order it will print a receipt with the barcode so that they can use the receipt to make payment at different locations, so I want the receipt to print automatically

Comment: @ADyson is it possible if i use a hosting company that is hosted in my country or if there is a way to auto print using javascript?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229048/discussion-between-j-doe-and-adyson).

Comment: `is it possible if i use a hosting company that is hosted in my country`...Please read again my comment which starts with _The geographical location is irrelevant_ ...

Comment: `if there is a way to auto print using javascript`...no there isn't, the user must consent. You can open the print dialog for them, but they must confirm before it will start printing. most users would be happy with that though, it's what they are used to in all web applications. Some might not want to print it at all, but simply save the receipt to their device.

Comment: @ADyson thank you so much for this information, so all the POS system which are used in the stores they are not connected online, they are just linked to the same LAN network?

Comment: Yes. Usually the application is installed on the device in the store. Maybe it talks to a database on a remote server, but the application will be installed locally, and so it can print locally. At most perhaps it's a web application which is hosted on another server within the same network (rather than elsewhere on a public internet site). I suggest you learn a little more about networking and about NAT (Network Address Translation) and how it protects access to private networks.